# How can I import a custom Portable text editor into my schema files

Tags: sanity

Trying to build on text editor and share it among all the schemas that need it in Sanity but cannot figure out how this is done.

I did look through the docs but they just build it to show in the view, I was unable to locate anything that was showing how to share this in the CMS everywhere.

I have a file called `richtextEditor.js` in my lib file for the moment and am trying to just import it and use it in one of my schemas but cannot get it dialed in.  The path is correct in the schema at `../../lib/richtextEditor.js` but the syntax for how to place this in the field for the Text editor I cannot get dialed in.  what I currently have, that is not working, is

```
    {
      title: 'Abstract',
      name: 'abstract',
      type: 'array',
      of: editor
    },
```

I had to place the imported editor into the `of:` area because it complained about that not being there but now it just complains about the syntax of the file, but it is exactly the same as when it was directly in this file and working so there is not a syntax issue with the file but something getting wonky once it gets imported

Answer (score 0):

One of the comprehensive approach that I can think of is

**1. Project Structure:**

- Create a dedicated `components` directory within your Sanity project's
  root to store reusable components. Move your `richtextEditor.js` file
  to this `components` directory.

**2. Component Definition:**

- Create the richtextEditor.js file with the following structure:

**JavaScript**

```
import React from 'react';
import { PortableText } from 'sanity-portable-text';

// Define your custom rich text components here
const serializers = {
  // ... your custom serializer definitions
};

const RichTextEditor = ({ value }) => {
  return <PortableText value={value} components={serializers} />;
};

export default RichTextEditor;
```

- Replace `// ... your custom serializer definitions` with the actual
  logic to define your custom rich text components (bold, italic,
  links, etc.). You can find examples and guidance in the Sanity
  documentation. I'll leave you the link here
  (https://www.sanity.io/docs/presenting-block-text)
- This component takes a `value` prop containing the Portable Text data
  to render.

**3. Schema Integration:**

- In your schemas, import and use the RichTextEditor component:

**JavaScript**

```
export default {
  title: 'Document',
  name: 'document',
  type: 'document',
  fields: [
    {
      title: 'Abstract',
      name: 'abstract',
      type: 'array',
      of: [{ type: 'block' }], // Specify the block types allowed in the editor
    },
    {
      title: 'Body',
      name: 'body',
      type: 'array',
      of: [{ type: 'reference', to: [{ type: 'richTextComponent' }] }], // Reference the rich text component
    },
    // ... other fields
  ],
};
```

**Explanation:**

1. Import RichTextEditor:

**JavaScript**

```
import RichTextEditor from '../components/richtextEditor'; // Adjust path as needed
```

2. Use the reference type:

- `type: 'reference'`: This indicates that the field will hold references
  to a specific document type.
- `to: [{ type: 'richTextComponent' }]`: This refers to the document
  type named richTextComponent (create this in a separate schema file
  if you haven't already).

**4. Rich Text Component Schema (optional tho):**

If you need additional control over the rich text editor configuration (allowed blocks, etc.), create a separate document type for it:
**JavaScript**

```
export default {
  title: 'Rich Text Component',
  name: 'richTextComponent',
  type: 'document',
  fields: [
    {
      title: 'Content',
      name: 'content',
      type: 'array',
      of: [{ type: 'block' }], // Specify the allowed block types here
    },
  ],
};
```

- Update the reference field in your main schema to point to this new
  `richTextComponent` type:

**JavaScript**

```
{
  title: 'Body',
  name: 'body',
  type: 'array',
  of: [{ type: 'reference', to: [{ type: 'richTextComponent' }] }],
},
```